# Identify thick grassy lumps in my lawn

Tags: grass, weeds

I'm a bit of a gardening newbie, so I hope this is not a stupid question.
I've noticed a few thick grassy lumps appearing on my lawn. They're much thicker and have grass-like leaves growing from little "branches". The roots appear similar to "normal lawn grass" (see pictures). I've searched online and it could be "couch grass", but am not sure. So, perhaps maybe someone here can shed some light on this. Any help identifying this (and how to deal with it) is much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Mark[image: grass detail][image: lawn]

Comment: It's not couch grass. Couch grass has long white "roots" (actually rhizomes) which is how it spreads quickly. See the picture at https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=283. What country/state are you in? Some of these weeds in grass are not world-wide.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I’m in the UK (London area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a wild meadow or weed grass of some sort - these sometimes appear in lawns and are not deterred by lawn weedkillers. It might be one known as Yorkshire Fog, but because its blades have been cut down, it's hard to be sure. The only way to deal with them is to dig out the clump, then repair the hole left behind by filling in with soil and spreading seed, or some turf. However, if there are a lot of clumps, the recommended course is to deeply slash into the centre with a sharp knife prior to mowing. This second course of action may not get rid of the weed grass entirely, but should, over time, discourage it.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo, There are quite a few clumps and I'm actually quite intrigued by your second suggestion, so I'm going to give that a try. Many thanks!